# apex:inlineEditSupport for a child (apex:repeat based HTML) table within a parent (apex:pageBlockTable) table is not working

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable, inlineeditsupport

Background: 
There is a Request object that could have multiple POs. A PO could have multiple Change Orders. POs and Change Orders are being displayed at the Request level via apex:repeat based HTML table (for Change Orders) nested within a parent apex:pageBlockTable (for PO). See below.

[image]

I am using a Standard Controller and pulling the data via ONE nested SOQL query like so: SELECT PO_NAME, Id, (SELECT CO_NAME, Id FROM PO_DETAIL__R) FROM PO__c WHERE Request__c =: request_id;

Goal:
I would like to give the user an ability to update data in ANY column and/or row at PO and/or Change Order level from that one screen with one Save button. So I used apex:inlineEditSupport.

Issue:
Although apex:inlineEditSupport works at the PO record level, it doesn't seem to work at the Change Order level.

Printing the List in Debug Logs doesn't even display the related Change Order list, but shows just the PO fields. Is this how it is or am I missing something?

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I manually handled the related list update:

```
List<PO_Detail__c> po_detail_list = new List<PO_Detail__c>();

for(PO__c po : po_info)
    po_detail_list.addAll(po.PO_Detail__r);

update po_detail_list;
```

where `po_info` is the PO list = parent table data.